# Webservice-Client: Use plain-text xml instead of object hierarchy

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-ws

I am programming a simple proxy in java:

1. Read XML File
2. Send request to Web-Service
3. Read Web-Service response
4. Write response to file

My first attempt is using JAXB to read the xml-file and generating Java-Objects. 
Then I send the objects with JAX-WS (IBM WebSphere). 
I receive the response as a "ResponseObject" which is then generated into xml code. I write the XML-Code to a file.

This setup works good. But...

When sending the java objects to the WebService, xml is generated, and the response agains creates java objects. I really would not need those request and response objects. 
**Is there a way to directly invoke the WebService with plaintext xml?** And to read the response as plaintext xml, instead of those response objects?

(Lets assume the xml files are always valid.)

Thank you

Comment: If you're dealing with plain text, you don't need JAXB or JAX-WS. Simply use an HTTP connection to send and receive strings.

Comment: Thanks sfussenegger. But i need some help to build the SOAP-messages. Is there a library that can handle the soap stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One could use [SAAJ](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/SAAJ.html#wp69380) (SOAP with Attachments API for Java) which runs at a lower level than JAX-WS. I expect it to use less system resources than JAX-WS.

See the following example (copied from [users.skynet.be/pascalbotte/rcx-ws-doc/saajpost.htm](http://users.skynet.be/pascalbotte/rcx-ws-doc/saajpost.htm#ID1-6-2))

> No more dynamic construction of the SOAP message this time, let's use a simple text editor and type the soap message we want to send.
>
> Example 1-13. The formated SOAP message in a text file: prepared.msg

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
 SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ans1:readLS xmlns:ans1="http://phonedirlux.homeip.net/types">
   <String_1 xsi:type="xsd:string">your message or e-mail</String_1>
  </ans1:readLS>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

> Now the code will be shorter and you can easily use it for testing purpose.
>
> Example 1-14. Post a SOAP message in a text file, to a web service using SAAJ

```
  import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
  import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
  import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
  import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
  import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;

  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

  import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
  import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
  import javax.xml.transform.Source;

  import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

  public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
 // Create the connection
 SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
 SOAPConnection conn = scf.createConnection();

 // Create message
 MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
 SOAPMessage msg = mf.createMessage();

 // Object for message parts
 SOAPPart sp = msg.getSOAPPart();
 StreamSource prepMsg = new StreamSource(
   new FileInputStream("path/prepared.msg"));
 sp.setContent(prepMsg);

 // Save message
 msg.saveChanges();

 // View input
 System.out.println("\n Soap request:\n");
 msg.writeTo(System.out);
 System.out.println();

 // Send
 String urlval = "http://www.pascalbotte.be/rcx-ws/rcx";
 SOAPMessage rp = conn.call(msg, urlval);

 // View the output
 System.out.println("\nXML response\n");

 // Create transformer
 TransformerFactory tff = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 Transformer tf = tff.newTransformer();

 // Get reply content
 Source sc = rp.getSOAPPart().getContent();

 // Set output transformation
 StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
 tf.transform(sc, result);
 System.out.println();

 // Close connection
 conn.close();

      }
      catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
```